# Should the number of normal samples always be more than that of anomalous samples in training set for anomaly detection?

Tags: svm, unbalanced-classes, train, anomaly-detection

I am trying to train an anomaly detection algorithm (one-class svm) on a data set with a few hundred positive samples and several thousands negative examples.

Is it mandatory that I train the model on the negative samples just because they are majority?

Thanks